# Facebook Like is sharing the wrong url

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a site that when a Facebook like button is used, it always has the URL of a different post.

Example: http://goo.gl/7SSy4f

I have used different plugins, and even added my own like button and they all do the same thing. The only thing that fixes it is if I change the template, which is not an option unfortunately

Any ideas?

---

### UPDATE

---

I found the following in the WordPress loop.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : 

                    $post = $posts[0]; // Hack. Set $post so that the_date() works. ?>
                    <?php /* If this is a category archive */ if (is_category()) { ?>
                  <h3><?php printf(__('Archive for the &#8216;%s&#8217; Category', TEXTDOMAIN), single_cat_title('', false)); ?></h3>
                    <?php /* If this is a tag archive */ } elseif( is_tag() ) { ?>
                  <h3><?php printf(__('Posts Tagged &#8216;%s&#8217;', TEXTDOMAIN), single_tag_title('', false) ); ?></h3>
                    <?php /* If this is a daily archive */ } elseif (is_day()) { ?>
                  <h3><?php printf(__('Archive for %s | Daily archive page', TEXTDOMAIN), get_the_time(__('F jS, Y', TEXTDOMAIN))); ?></h3>
                    <?php /* If this is a monthly archive */ } elseif (is_month()) { ?>
                  <h3><?php printf(__('Archive for %s | Monthly archive page', TEXTDOMAIN), get_the_time(__('F Y', TEXTDOMAIN))); ?></h3>
                    <?php /* If this is a yearly archive */ } elseif (is_year()) { ?>
                  <h3><?php printf(__('Archive for %s | Yearly archive page', TEXTDOMAIN), get_the_time(__('Y', TEXTDOMAIN))); ?></h3>
                    <?php /* If this is a yearly archive */ } elseif (is_search()) { ?>
                  <h3><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', TEXTDOMAIN ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h3>
                   <?php /* If this is an author archive */ } elseif (is_author()) { ?>               
                  <h3><?php _e('Author Archive', TEXTDOMAIN); ?></h3>
                    <?php /* If this is a paged archive */ } elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) { ?>
                  <h3><?php _e('Blog Archives', TEXTDOMAIN); ?></h3>        
                    <?php } 

                      while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

                        global $more;

                        if(!is_single()) $more = 0;

                        $type_blog = ( $GLOBALS['yiw_custom_blog_type'] != false ) ? $GLOBALS['yiw_custom_blog_type'] : get_option( $GLOBALS['shortname'] . '_blog_type', 'classic' );
                    ?>
```

I am pretty sure it is something with this (fingers crossed) but I am unable to find a fix for it. Any help would be great! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you are using a widget or other custom query that is not calling [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) to change back to the default `global $post`.

If you can't change the theme try disabling widgets or looking through the for places that set the `$post` object.